# Bootstrap CCS ul width issue - list elements arent as wide as the parent element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a layout with bootstrap 3 and am finding an odd property:

here is the code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container center-form panel admin">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ul class="list-unstyled" ng-repeat="app in apps | filter:query ">
                <li> 
                <h4> <a ui-sref="/api/admin/{{app._id}}">{{app.name}}</a></h4>
                <div style="width:100%">
                <p class="pull-right"><small> Job ID: {{app._id}}</small></p>
                <p>Appointment Date: {{app.appointment_date | date:'fullDate'}}</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <address class="text-left"> 
                {{app.address_1}}</br>
                {{app.city}}</br>
                {{app.postcode}}</br>
                </address>
                        </hr>       
               </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The issue I'm having is that these are both within a Jumbotron container, and for some reason, the `<ul>` tag spans across the whole of the col-md-12 div, but the `<li>` and all the elements within it wont, and only takes up about half of it. So even thought I've added style="width: 100%" to div, it only fills half the screen.

How can I make the li element span the same width as the ul element ?

Comment: Can you create a working example based on the actual HTML output (not the preprocessed HTML) in a code hosting service like [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new)?

Comment: It does by default, see [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/RkAq0phMv4). I would guess you have something overriding that somewhere. Use the inspector to see what's affecting your `<li>`'s